A story about tiny beings
They are creating a vessel to leave their world.  Turns out they are building an amphibious ship that can cross a small ridge of sand or dirt from their puddle to the next puddle.
And that they were created by a human explorer sent to terraform a primitive muddy planet.  He crashes and all he has are his own germ cells and DNA to use his lab to create a race of very tiny aquatic humanoids.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Duplicate of Trying to locate a Sci Fiction story about a humanoid micro-sized in a pool.

Please accept  @DoscoJones 's answer if it answers your question.

This question is similar to: Trying to locate a Sci Fiction story about a humanoid micro-sized in a pool. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@WoJ we only close story ID questions as dupes if they both have an accepted answer

Surface Tension, James Blish, Galaxy Science Fiction, 1952.
From Wikipedia:

A human colonization ship crash-lands on a distant planet which is
Earth-like but whose only landmass is completely covered in shallow
puddles of water and mostly microscopic life forms. Normal humans
could not survive on this planet, so the crew must genetically
engineer their descendants into something that can survive. (Blish
coined the term pantropy to refer to this concept.) They create a race
of microscopic aquatic humanoids to complete their mission and
colonize the planet.
The majority of the story concerns one group of these genetically
engineered colonists and their intelligence, curiosity, and evolving
technology. In particular, the tiny aquatic humanoids develop a "space
ship", or rather "air ship", which enables them to pierce the
previously impenetrable surface tension of the water and travel
through what is, to them, hostile space—open air—to other worlds in
other puddles of water.

You can read it here.
